# ls -a command is not working on my vs code terminal what should i do?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

```
PS C:\Users\sampr\Desktop\Git-demo\LocalRepo> ls -a
Get-ChildItem : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'a' is
ambiguous. Possible matches include: -Attributes -Directory -File -Hidden -ReadOnly      
-System.
At line:1 char:4
+ ls -a
+    ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingExc  
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameter,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChild  
   ItemCommand
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XubIF.png)

Help me with full solution and with picture

Comment: You're trying to use a Unix shell command _in PowerShell_, maybe don't do that.

Comment: Read the words in the error message. They tell you **exactly** what is wrong, and what the allowable keywords starting with `a` are for that version of ls. The words are there for a reason, not just to take up space on your screen. They contain information that usually tells you how to solve the problem, if you **read the words** in the message.

Answer (score 0):

In Powershell, `-a` doesn't exist as a parameter. I get the same error on my system:
[image: A picture of a Powershell terminal]

You're probably using Powershell as your terminal in VS Code which doesn't use the same parameters as BASH in Linux.

So as an alternative what you can do is use `Get-ChildItem` to list everything in your directory instead:
[image: Powershell with Get-ChildItem]

Comment: I'm using vs code (terminal) and when I use Get-ChildItem it just skips and moves forward to the second command line.

Comment: It's possible the directory you're in is empty, I tried it on my VS code terminal in an empty directory and got the same skip. Is it not working for any directory ??